# where should i add the csrf token in this?

Tags: html, django, jinja2

i really don`t understand what most of this html does as i am not comfortable with html. along with the location of where to add the token if one could explain to me what most of this does it would be greatly appreciated

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/body.css">
<body>

<div class="bgimg w3-display-container w3-text-black">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-jumbo">
    <button class=" w3-button w3-white">HSEA STOCK</button>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-container w3-xlarge ">
    <p><button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button></p>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="id01" class="modal">

  <form class="modal-content animate" action="/login" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required

      <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="passwword" required>

      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
```

sorry if this seams very obvious but i did not make this page and i am having trouble adding the csrf token for django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take advantage of **CSRF** protection in your views, follow these steps:

1. The CSRF middleware is activated by default in the **`MIDDLEWARE`**
   setting. If you override that setting, remember that
   **`'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'`** should come before any
   view middleware that assume that CSRF attacks have been dealt with.
2. If you disabled it, which is not recommended, you can use **`csrf_protect()`** on particular views you want to protect (see below).
3. In any template that uses a POST form, use the **`csrf_token`** tag inside the **`<form>`** element if the form is for an internal URL, e.g.:

   `<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}`
4. This should not be done for **POST** forms that target external URLs, since that would cause the CSRF token to be leaked, leading to a vulnerability.
5. In the corresponding view functions, ensure that **`RequestContext`** is used to render the response so that **`{% csrf_token %}`** will work properly. If you’re using the **`render()`** function, generic views, or contrib apps, you are covered already since these all use **`RequestContext`**.

> Note
>
> The CSRF token is also present in the DOM, but only if explicitly
>   included using **`csrf_token`** in a template. The cookie contains the
>   canonical token; the **`CsrfViewMiddleware`** will prefer the cookie to the
>   token in the DOM. Regardless, you’re guaranteed to have the cookie if
>   the token is present in the DOM, so you should use the cookie!

And Warning

> Warning
>
> If your view is not rendering a template containing the **`csrf_token`**
>   template tag, Django might not set the CSRF token cookie. This is
>   common in cases where forms are dynamically added to the page. To
>   address this case, Django provides a view decorator which forces
>   setting of the cookie: **`ensure_csrf_cookie().`**

Using **CSRF** in **Jinja2** templates

Django’s **Jinja2** template backend adds **`{{ csrf_input }}`** to the context of all templates which is equivalent to **`{% csrf_token %}`** in the Django template language. For example:

```
<form method="post">{{ csrf_input }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF token is always placed after the initialization form tag. And after that all the input fields.

```
<form>
  {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

the official django documentation is clear, check it out at 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it